# Substitute real values into derived symbols using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, physics, equation-solving

I am trying to evaluate the value of an equation by substituting in the values.

```
exp=2*C_0*Derivative(theta(t), t, t) - C_1 - 2*C_2*theta(t)
```

The above is the equation and I have the data for the angle(theta) and angular velocity and acceleration. The above equation is a form of the Euler-Lagrange equation.

I know that I could use

```
exp.subs{list_of_variables[0]:2}
```

to substitute into theta but how do I do it for dynamic symbols?

The dynamic symbols have been defined as follows.

```
list_of_variables=[dynamicsymbols("theta"),dynamicsymbols("theta",1)]
```

Comment: In your expression you have the angle and angular acceleration but in you list of variables you have theta and angular velocity. Is this a typo?

Comment: No but I have specified the angular acceleration by expanding the list of variables. 

Its worked now